# Slim and Doctrine unable to SQL select

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, slim

I am trying to make a connection to my mySQL database. 
But I am not understanding this controller thing in Slim. 
I am using https://github.com/napolux/helloslim3 as a boilerplate, I have my DB configuration on *settings.php*

**API Controller**

```
    use Slim\Http\Request;
    use Slim\Http\Response;

    use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

    /**
     * Class ApiController
     * @package ESTORE\Controller
     */
    class ApiController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @param Request $request
         * @param Response $response
         * @param $args
         * @return Response
         */
        public function apiExample(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
        {

          $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
          var_dump($conn);die;

            $responseArray = ["thisis" => "an api response"];
            return $response->withJSON($responseArray);
        }
    }
```

If I go to `localhost/api` I get

```
Call to undefined method ESTORE\Controller\ApiController::getEntityManager() in /Users/tiagosa/Documents/e-store/src/Controller/ApiController.php on line 24
```

Thanks

Comment: You should extend sf2 controller. You are extending that abstract controller, is that abstract extending the sf2 controller ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Comment: @LuisLopes you mean use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; ?

Comment: No. He means: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.  Are you even using the Symfony framework or just some components?  If you are using the framework, why not follow the Symfony documentation and examples instead of the Slim documentation?  Nevermind.  I just read you code a little closer.  It is clear you are not using the Symfony framework.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Symfony application, so things such as `$this->getEntityManager()` are not available in your controller.

It appears you want to use the documentation here to get started:
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html